# Dart Navigator gives NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, sdk, dart, flutter

I need help, I'm trying to display a new page when a button is pressed. I get the following error:

```
I/flutter (31562): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (31562): Class 'MyHomePage' has no instance getter 'context'.
I/flutter (31562): Receiver: Instance of 'MyHomePage'
I/flutter (31562): Tried calling: context
I/flutter (31562): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

Here is my Code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{

  Container pictureSection(){
    return new Container(
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/sw.jpeg',
        width: 600.0,
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container mainMenuSection(){
    var spacer = new SizedBox(height: 12.0);
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          spacer,
          new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/PlanetsPage');},
            child: new Text('Get Planet'),
            ),
          spacer,
          ],
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var spacer = new SizedBox(height: 32.0);
    var spacer2 = new SizedBox(height: 15.0);
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            pictureSection(),
            mainMenuSection(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlanetsPage extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          child: new Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
      '/PlanetsPage': (BuildContext context) => new PlanetsPage(),
    },
  ));
}
```

I'm trying to go from the Home Page to the Planets Page when the button is pressed, and the error only shows up when I press the button. I am using my Hauwei Nova to do the testing on.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `BuildContext` from the `build` method instead of using the `context` member of `MyHomePage`. See below:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{

  Container pictureSection(){
    return new Container(
      child: new Image.asset(
        'images/sw.jpeg',
        width: 600.0,
        height: 240.0,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container mainMenuSection(BuildContext context){
    var spacer = new SizedBox(height: 12.0);
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          spacer,
          new RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/PlanetsPage');},
            child: new Text('Get Planet'),
            ),
          spacer,
          ],
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    var spacer = new SizedBox(height: 32.0);
    var spacer2 = new SizedBox(height: 15.0);
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            pictureSection(),
            mainMenuSection(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlanetsPage extends StatelessWidget{
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          child: new Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main(){
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
      '/PlanetsPage': (BuildContext context) => new PlanetsPage(),
    },
  ));
}
```